# Website Access...DNS, ISP, issue?

Tags: dns, isp

This isn't so much a code issue as it might be an issue with my ISP.  For some reason when I visit a site very often, like one I manage or write stories on, it will just stop pulling data down after a while.  It's very random when it happens, but probably happens once a week.

If effects everyone who is accessing the site from this connection, and I can access other sites no problem.  Also, if I go outside the office back home, which is right down the street, and access the site it is fine.  I'm using Comcast in both locations.

It's almost as if I have a limit on requests to each site and have hit my limit so it blocks the site for a while.

Anybody have any clue what this might be?

Comment: Have you tried doing a traceroute, to see if a hop is a bit faulty? On windows `tracert the-domain.com`

Answer (score 1):

Your ISP is probably caching requests to those sites (a little too aggressively, by the sounds of it). Unfortunately, you can't clear your ISP's cache in the same way that you can clear your browser cache, so there's little you can do about it beyond:

1. Waiting for their cache to expire (usually around 24 hours).
2. Changing your ISP.
3. Connecting via a VPN, which bypasses your ISP's caching mechanisms. (I use [StrongVPN](http://strongvpn.com/).)